# nhibernate interceptors with domain context

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, interceptor, auditing

Is it possible (in a clean fashion) to create an audit interceptor in hibernate 2.1 and pass in a domain context to it?

What I would like to achieve is to set a Date Time (can be done easy peasy - found loadsa articles after a quick google), but setting an object e.g. a user who created the item, or altered an entity I have yet to find anything which covers this.

Since I will not know the object at application request/start up (which is where i have to register the nhibernate interceptor), does anyone know of a suitable workaround?

Thanks in advance, Mark H

Comment: [EDIT]: The same above, or with nhibernate listeners, i am happy to use whatever gets the job done!

Answer (score 2):

You can store the user in the current session (`HttpContext.Session`) or use `thread local` data. It can then be accessed by the listener. If you go for the thread local approach, you will need to set if for each request, for instance with an `HttpModule`. Not perfect, but that's how I've [seen it done in java](http://markatta.com/johan/codemonkey/?p=58) (not exactly the same, but a similar approach).